# How to remove all occurrences of .DS_Store in a folder

Tags: linux, command-line, directory, rm, recursive

Think of it as going to the most high level folder, doing a Ctrl Find, and searching .DS_Store and deleting them all.

I want them all deleted, from all subfolders and subfolders subfolders and so on. Basically inside the top level folder, there should be no .DS_Store file anywhere, not even in any of its subfolders.

What would be the command I should enter?

Comment: If you're on a mac they are going to automatically recreate themselves.  Try this guide to disable it:  http://pixelcog.com/blog/2016/disable-ds_store-in-el-capitan/

Comment: The OP tagged Linux; can the OP confirm or deny being on MacOS?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Ah, I skipped over the tags.  I just know of ds_store as a mac thing however I'm assuming he's copied the files off a mac to linux which is an issue I deal with often as well.

Comment: Yes I am on a linux machine

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
find top-folder -type f -name '.DS_Store' -exec rm -f {} +
```

or, more simply,

```
find top-folder -type f -name '.DS_Store' -delete
```

where `top-folder` is the path to the top folder you'd like to look under.

To print out the paths of the found files before they get deleted:

```
find top-folder -type f -name '.DS_Store' -print -exec rm -f {} +
```